# ESLint configuration in package.json » eslint-config-react-app is invalid:

Tags: typescript, eslint

- Property "overrides" is the wrong type (expected array but got `{"files":["**/*.ts","**/*.tsx"],"parser":"@typescript-eslint/parser","parserOptions":{"ecmaVersion":2018,"sourceType":"module","ecmaFeatures":{"jsx":true},"warnOnUnsupportedTypeScriptVersion":true},"plugins":["@typescript-eslint"],"rules":{"default-case":"off","no-dupe-class-members":"off","@typescript-eslint/no-angle-bracket-type-assertion":"warn","no-array-constructor":"off","@typescript-eslint/no-array-constructor":"warn","@typescript-eslint/no-namespace":"error","no-unused-vars":"off","@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars":["warn",{"args":"none","ignoreRestSiblings":true}],"no-useless-constructor":"off","@typescript-eslint/no-useless-constructor":"warn"}}`).

Referenced from: D:{app folder}{app name}\package.json

Comment: What's unclear from the error message? `"overrides"` expects an array `[...]` but got an object `{...}`.

Comment: i clone this repo and when i do npm start i get this problem can you please help me out

Comment: You clone _what_ repo, why don't you bring it up with whoever maintains it? If you're asking here we'd need a [mre] - I'd suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I actually had this same issue when updating `react-scripts` in my Create React App Project. My steps to resolve were.

- Delete `package-lock.json`
- Delete `node_modules`
- Remove `eslint` dependencies from your `devDependencies` in `package.json`
- run `npm cache clear --force`
- `npm install`
- `npm install` the the latest versions of the `eslint` packages you removed back to your `devDependencies`
- Restart your project and see if it is fixed.

This worked for me.

**UPDATE:** I actually did not need to install eslint after removing them when installing React Scripts 5. It seems to use it under the hood.

Comment: deleting `node_modules` and running `npm install` worked for me. Thanks.